# swt label extra space on the top (inside the border)

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I am creating a label, but when I draw a border around it, it shows that there is a small space immediately above the number inside the border. I want to make the label such that the border touches the number on on all sides. 
Any ideas on how to do it?
I am doing this-

```
    final Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.verticalSpacing = 0;
    layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
    layout.marginHeight = 0;
    layout.marginWidth = 0;
    composite.setLayout(layout);
    composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.NONE, false, false));

    Label numberLabel = new Label(composite, SWT.BORDER);
    numberLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.NONE, false, false));
```

I found this site to upload an image to be shared - http://i59.tinypic.com/24mrhgp.png

Answer (score 1):

You can draw label on canvas to get fine control over drawing. [Refer this article on canvas](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-graphics/SWT_graphics.html)

Adjust parameters of the method `e.gc.drawRectangle` to get fine control.

Example:

```
package testplugin;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SWTHelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);       
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());      
        final Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        layout.verticalSpacing = 0;
        layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
        layout.marginHeight = 0;
        layout.marginWidth = 0;
        composite.setLayout(layout);
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.NONE, false, false));

        Label numberLabel = new Label(composite, SWT.BORDER);
        numberLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.NONE, false, false));
        numberLabel.setText("84");

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE);            
        canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

            @Override
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                e.gc.drawString("84", 0, 0);
                Point pt = e.gc.stringExtent("84");             
                e.gc.drawRectangle(0, 2, pt.x-1, pt.y-4);
            }

        });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        shell.setSize(200, 300);
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and suggestion. I wont be able to use this as the rectangle's size will be different in different resolutions and machines.
I figured there would be an easier way as there is an image label and if I draw borders around it, it shows that it touches all the sides well.